# (Ubuntu 20.10) Online Accounts: Facebook "App Not Setup" after login

Tags: facebook

After logging into Facebook through Online Accounts in Ubuntu's Settings, I receive the error `App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or as an app admin for permissions.`

Is there a misconfiguration in the GNOME Facebook integration, or am I supposed to set myself up as a tester?

OS: Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: There is a [GNOME bug report](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-online-accounts/-/issues/128) for this.